# elementary OS does not boot after 0.3.2 update

Tags: boot, system, grub, updates

After the last update and rebooting a Grub screen showed. Totally new, as I have elementary OS as my main and sole OS. The options it gives are -elementary OS -Advance Options for elementary OS, which gives some different Linux kernels (5 differents kernel options). Choosing any always leads to `[   1.689766] ACPI PCC probe failed.`
And then to something called BusyBox v.1.21.1. The OS does never load, before formating, and re-installing it again (because I love this linux flavour) and losing all my music and videos, well, i'd like to know if there's something I can do to fix it, if broken.

Comment: And I didn't know what tags to use, so I used those. But if anyone knows better tags, well let me know.

Comment: Amazingly, we've had a release (0.3.2) within the last few hours that should fix a whole host of issues with booting. Could you try that and get back to us?

Comment: Hey Lewis, thanks for The quick response. I'll try that. But can you tell me how to do it from BusyBox?

Comment: I have busybox-initramfs and busybox-static installed, but I have no idea how to use them I'm afraid. I think you are going to have to re-install from scratch. Do you have nothing else to create installation media on?

Comment: I have a pendrive with freya on it. So there's nothing to do about it? What a pity... Hey, thanks again, should i close this question to answered ir should I wait for some Otero idea?

Comment: If you have another spare pendrive, you could make one from your current pendrive. If not, I wouldn't know how to proceed, but there might be an alternative solution, since it worked at one time.